# AWS Ubuntu can't ssh after install apache

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04

On our EC2 instance (t2/Ubuntu) I've been able to ssh to the instance but can't any longer.

I installed Apache and then tried accessing the web server via the IP. With no luck I assumed possibly firewall issue so I then tried using the command

```
sudo ufw allow 'Apache'
```

and I believe I received "inactive", so I then entered the following

```
sudo ufw enable
```

After issuing the above and checking the ufw status I got

```
Output Status: active

To           Action From
--           ------ ----

OpenSSH (v6) ALLOW  Anywhere (v6)
Apache (v6)  ALLOW  Anywhere (v6)
```

I then tried to ssh from the 2 accounts I had setup, but can no longer access the server via SSH.

Did I block SSH? If so how do I open this up again?

Answer (score 1):

To get this working either disable firewall or allow required port in firewall. Off course, still you need to login into ec2 instance to get this done. There are 3 ways to connect with ec2 instance
[image]

SSH is not working so I choose Session Manager (Browser based ssh). I follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uE0jGmZ2PRc) and was able to connect with instance through session manager.

After login i just disable the firewall and every thing works fine.

```
sudo ufw disable
```

All the inbound rules working properly.

Answer (score 0):

“This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.”

following infomation may be helpful to you
- check port `telnet 1.2.3.4 22`
- use`-vvvv`get more infomation `ssh user@ip -vvvv`

Comment: Sorry, don't follow; when I try to ssh (ssh user@ip -vvv)  from another server/terminal I get connection timeout

Comment: I think this post might have been well-intentioned... but the message [*"This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here"*](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) does not mean what I suspect you might believe it to mean.